# Unfortunately settings has stopped working, can't get past Welcome setup

Tags: settings, factory-reset, setup-wizard

In advance, I would like to say sorry for my bad English, and that this is my first time posting here so I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly. If I am, it would be nice for me to know.

I have a Alcatel One Touch Fierce, althought I do not know much about it. It is not an XL or a Fierce 2 as far as I am aware, but it is from T-Mobile. For a while now I have been getting been getting a 'Unfortunately, Settings has stopped.' error, when trying to simply open Settings from the home screen or application drawer. I had then reset the phone to factory settings which after doing so, brings me to a Welcome Setup screen. I will attach what this screen looks like. If you can't read it says:

Welcome Setup

For later reference you can find the Setup application in the main menu.

There is a button that show 'Get Started'.

[image: Welcome Setup]

When I press it, it sends me to a language select menu, between English and Spanish. If i select either and press next, it shows the same error message again: Unfortunately, settings has stopped working. I would like to note that this is error is coming straight from ANDROID'S settings app, not Google Settings.

I have tried powering the phone off and launching it with volume up and power button and in recovery mode. I have tried resetting to factory mode and clearing cache, but nothing seemed to help.

Bottom line - My phone displays Unfortunately settings has stopped working eror and I cannot get past the Setup screen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138159/discussion-on-question-by-mark-radford-unfortunately-settings-has-stopped-workin).